# How to start ubuntu without executing rc.local

Tags: boot

I added my script to /etc/rc.local file and now ubuntu hangs. ctr+alt+f1 does not work. I only see black screen with one blinking charcter `-`. 
How to resolve it? Maby there is some emergency booting and I could boot system without executing rc.local file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Booting into recovery mode - select 'network' to enable editing stuff:

[image]

<sub>This is for versions later than 12.04....</sub>

Then selecting 'root', and running `chmod -x /etc/rc.local` might work...

Hope this helps [image: smiley]

Comment: There is some other cause of problem. I removed my script from rc.local file and removed permission to execute. But there is steel the same problem. if I boot to recovery mode to root shell and command `shutdown now` then ubuntu transit to `tty1`. tty1-tty6 works, but tty7 has steel blindig dash. I recall that in the normal mode ther is only blinding dash and any of tty does not work.

Comment: `tty7` is normally the one for the graphical desktop in Ubuntu. Have you done any change that might of caused this problem, including the script in `rc.local`...? It could be anything from a bug in Login manager to Graphic cards drivers... :-s

Comment: I executed `sudo apt-get install -f` ,  `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Updates may case this. Where should I look for logs about graphical desktop? I checked /var/log/syslog. I would like to point out that despite the fact that  tty7 does not work,  Graphic cards work. I know that because cgminer application detects and uses graphic cards.

Comment: Does sound like updates - a system that works if often better than a system that is up to date.... If you are sure it is updates, you may want to ask a question on how to do it, as it can vary by graphic cards...